# Why $\langle x_i,x_{jk}\rangle=0$ holds true?

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I am reading the paper ["Minimal Immersions of 2-Manifolds into Spheres"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01174890). In (1.1), page 379, the author wrote that $\langle x_i,x_{jk}\rangle=0$. I don't know why this equality holds true but I think this is not a difficult one. Did I miss something? I would be grateful if someone could help me!

The link is behind a paywall, so I explain more about the notations here:

$(M,g)$ is a closed connected 2-dimensional Riemannian manifold.

Consider the isometric minimal immersions $\tilde{x}:M\rightarrow\mathbb{S}^N(1)$.

$j:\mathbb{S}^N(1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$ is the canonical embedding.

$x:=j\circ\tilde{x}$.

$x_i,x_{jk}$ is the covariant derivatives.

$\langle,\rangle$ is the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}$.

Comment: Your link is behind a paywall. You may need to explain more about the notations

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks for your advice. I added some explanation.

Comment: Not nearly enough explanation. Using $j$ for an index and for a mapping at the same time is horrendous, but I assume that was not your choice. You still need to give more details. What kind of coordinates are $u^i$ on $M$? What do we know about $\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$?

Comment: @TedShifrin I post part of the paper and you can see if it's enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So nothing specific was assumed about the local coordinates. This is just the usual cyclic permutation trick for solving for Christoffel symbols. Before we start, note that the covariant derivatives $x_{ij}$ and $x_{ji}$ are equal:
\begin{align*}
x_{ij} &= \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial u^j\partial u^i} + \sum\Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u^k} \\
&= \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial u^i\partial u^j} + \sum\Gamma^k_{ji}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u^k} \\
&= x_{ji},
\end{align*}
since the connection is torsion-free.

Since the connection is compatible with the Riemannian metric, we have
$$0 = \nabla_{\partial/\partial u^k} g_{ij} = \langle x_i,x_{jk}\rangle + \langle x_{ik},x_j\rangle.$$
We cyclically permute, and do the usual $+$ $-$ $+$ trick:
\begin{alignat*}2
0 &= \langle x_i,x_{jk}\rangle + \langle x_{ik},x_j\rangle & \quad (+) \\
0 &= \langle x_j,x_{ki}\rangle + \langle x_{ji},x_k\rangle & (-) \\
0 &= \langle x_k,x_{ki}\rangle + \langle x_{kj},x_i\rangle & (+)
\end{alignat*}
Using the symmetry of the covariant derivatives we asserted at the beginning, we end up with $2\langle x_i,x_{jk}\rangle = 0$, as desired.

Comment: Oh yes! I missed the symmetry so the cyclic permutation trick did not work. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry to bother you. I just have another question. Can we obtain any relations about the value of $\langle x_i,x_i\rangle$?

Comment: Not without further information.